# ORDER BY and UPDLOCK—A (Non-)Working Example

Tags: sql-server-2005, locking

Although I cannot disclose information about the real tables (if I could, I would) causing the problems described in my previous question, I built from scratch a (non-)working example which reproduces exactly (data-type by data-type, column size by column size) the problem I am facing. So I created a new database named "QueueTest" and ran the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE Request
(
    RequestID   BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    Priority    TINYINT,
    DateEntered DATETIME
)

CREATE TABLE Options
(
    RequestIDRef    BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    SomeOptions     NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

ALTER TABLE Options ADD

    CONSTRAINT FK_REQUESTIDREF FOREIGN KEY ( RequestIDRef ) REFERENCES [Request] ( RequestID )

GO

INSERT INTO Request VALUES ( 1, 2, GETDATE() )
INSERT INTO Request VALUES ( 2, 1, GETDATE() )
INSERT INTO Request VALUES ( 3, 3, GETDATE() )
INSERT INTO Request VALUES ( 4, 2, GETDATE() )

INSERT INTO Options VALUES ( 1, 'Options1' )
INSERT INTO Options VALUES ( 2, 'Options2' )
INSERT INTO Options VALUES ( 3, 'Options3' )
INSERT INTO Options VALUES ( 4, 'Options4' )

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_OPTIONS_REQUESTIDREF ON [Options] ( RequestIDRef )
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_REQUEST_PRIORITY_DATEENTERED ON [Request] ( Priority , DateEntered ) INCLUDE ( RequestID )
```

After that I opened two new queries, `Query1` and `Query2`, and ran the following scripts to simulate the problem:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT TOP 2 RequestID FROM ( Request R WITH ( ROWLOCK , UPDLOCK , READPAST ) INNER JOIN Options O WITH ( ROWLOCK , UPDLOCK , READPAST ) ON ( R.RequestID = O.RequestIDRef ) ) ORDER BY Priority ASC , DateEntered ASC

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02.500'

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

The results I got were

```
Query1 | Query 2
   2   |
   1   |
```

while I was, of course, expecting

```
Query1 | Query 2
   2   |    4
   1   |    3
```

So, I assume that even though I have the indexes described above, `Query1` is still locking the whole table. Here is the execution plan for both queries:

**Execution plan**

```
StmtText
-----------------------
SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON

(1 row(s) affected)

StmtText
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT TOP 2 RequestID FROM ( Request R WITH ( ROWLOCK , UPDLOCK , READPAST ) INNER JOIN Options O WITH ( ROWLOCK , UPDLOCK , READPAST ) ON ( R.RequestID = O.RequestIDRef ) ) ORDER BY Priority ASC , DateEntered ASC

(2 row(s) affected)

StmtText
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:((2)))
       |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, WHERE:([QueueTest].[dbo].[Options].[RequestIDRef] as [O].[RequestIDRef]=[QueueTest].[dbo].[Request].[RequestID] as [R].[RequestID]))
            |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([QueueTest].[dbo].[Request].[IX_REQUEST_PRIORITY_DATEENTERED] AS [R]), ORDERED FORWARD)
            |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([QueueTest].[dbo].[Options].[PK__Options__5366EEE80BC6C43E] AS [O]))

(4 row(s) affected)

StmtText
---------------------------------

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02.500'

COMMIT TRANSACTION

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Please notice that when I ran both queries with `SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON` I think the `WAITFOR DELAY` instruction was not respected-in fact, the first query completed immediately, so that when I ran the second one it had already completed.

What can be causing the locking problem? Please help me since I can't really figure it by myself.

**Edit:** Please note that I can't create a view with a `SELECT TOP 2` instruction. The `2` here is for illustration purposes, while in the real situation it is a parameter passed to a stored procedure which then runs this `SELECT`. Please note also that creating an indexed view using

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER VIEW TestView WITH SCHEMABINDING AS

    SELECT RequestID , Priority , DateEntered FROM( dbo.Request R INNER JOIN dbo.Options O ON ( R.RequestID = O.RequestIDRef ) )

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_TESTE_1 ON TestView ( RequestID )
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TESTE_2 ON TestView ( Priority ASC , DateEntered ASC ) INCLUDE ( RequestID )
```

and then selecting from `TestView WITH ( ROWLOCK , UPDLOCK , READPAST )` also didn't work, neither with nor without the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a "Clustered Index Scan" and an "Index Scan" which blocks all rows in both tables As I said in my previous answers.

Also from previous answers:

1. Use an indexed view
2. Don't have hints *in* view
3. Add NOEXPAND hint when you call the view

Finally, the index IX_REQUEST_PRIORITY_DATEENTERED does not have the JOIN condition. This may remove one of the Scans

If you won't listen to the "view" bit above, then try both of these

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_REQUEST_PRIORITY_DATEENTERED ON [Request]
  (RequestID , Priority , DateEntered )


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_REQUEST_PRIORITY_DATEENTERED ON [Request]
  (Priority , DateEntered , RequestID )
```

Comment: I was missing the `NOEXPAND` part. It worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, NOEXPAND forces the optimiser to use the indexed view. I should have thought earlier